# Today widget - executing openURL unlock iPhone not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, today-extension

I'm trying to create a today widget on IOS9
and I can't seem to figure out how to unlock the iPhone when pressing a button.

My widget:
when pressing it calls:
    self.extensionContext openURL
this is working when the iPhone is unlocked.
but I would like in the locked state, so when pressing the button and executing the openURL method that it goes to the unlock screen, and when unlocked it executes the openURL command.

(I can't find) There is no documentation on this topic or questions asked.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't. There is no public API for lock/unlock screen.

Comment: I get that, what I don't get is that all other widgets do go to the unlock screen went there need to go to the app. And when I press mine, it just don't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed that I used a system link, that isn't documented.
and it does not unlock the phone when executed.

the equivalent of this system link , uses a prompt but when locked goes to the unlock screen. and that is what I need.

(tel://) is a system link, and should not be used instead use (telprompt://)

my problem is solved.